# jquery add tag after another tag

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I currently have the following:

```
<h3>My Title</h3>
```

And would like to add the following:

```
<h3><span>My Title</span></h3>
```

I have tried to achieve this by the following:

```
$( "<h3>" ).replaceWith( "<h3><span>" );
$( "</h3>" ).replaceWith( "</span></h3>" );
```

But the above doesn't seem to be working. Am i approaching this in the correct way?

Comment: Use this: http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace an element like it is a string.

In this case you can use [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('h3').wrapInner('<span />');
})
```

```css
h3 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>My Title</h3>
<button>Wrap</button>
```